# Regular expression not working as expected. Replacing

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex

I'm pulling out my hair over the following function:

```
Public Function SetVersion(ByVal hl7Message As String, ByVal newVersion As String) As String
    Dim rgx = New Regex("^(?<pre>.+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
    Dim m = rgx.Match(hl7Message)
    Return rgx.Replace(hl7Message, "${pre}|" & newVersion, 1, 0)
End Function
```

For simplicity, I'm testing against the following input:

```
dsfdsaf|2.1
wretdfg|2.2
sdafasd3|2.3
```

What I need to accomplish is replace "|2.1" in the *first* line with another value, say "|2.4". What is happening instead is that "|2.3" is getting replaced in the *last* line. It's as if I hadn't specified Multi-Line mode. Moreover, the following [online tool](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) returned correct matches. So, anyone who can see a mistake in my regex or code, please point it out.

Comment: I've also tried the following Regex with the same result:
"^(?<pre>[^\r\n]+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})$"

Comment: I thought you made a rookie mistake as match only returns one result, but then i tried it and you do only get one return result. So still working on a solution. I should know this as i did some complex Regex in C# last year.

Comment: @JonWillis a year is a long time in regex land :)

Comment: @Ahmad, It sure is. I think its like XPath, if you don't use the skill you need to relearn it. My stuff from last year was checking if user entered strings were valid, frequencies/temperatures/numbers/decibels etc. If it was the formatter would display it in the lowest denominator whilst storing the actual value. It was useful but I built it when I was bored one week and never actually used it in a project to its full potential. CodeProject may make a good home for it as its mostly finished ;)

Comment: The second line in the function is there by accident. I was using Match to check for success. I forgot to remove before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying `$` you are essentially matching the last occurrence at the end of the string. If you want to match the first occurrence, remove the `$` or specify that a newline is expected:

```
"^(?<pre>.+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})"
```

or

```
"^(?<pre>.+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})[\r\n]"
```

Based on your comment about using Multiline and appearance of your test data I imagine your input is on multiple lines. Use the above pattern and try this:

```
Dim input As String = "dsfdsaf|2.1" & Environment.NewLine & _
                       "wretdfg|2.2" & Environment.NewLine & _
                       "sdafasd3|2.3"

Console.WriteLine("Before:")
Console.WriteLine(input)
Console.WriteLine("After:")
Console.WriteLine(SetVersion(input, "2.4"))
```

2.1 should change to 2.4.

Comment: Removing the $ worked. Thank you! I was under the impression that specifying multiline mode changed the meaning of $ to match end of line instead of end of string. I am used to referencing this guide: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html. Is this then just an eccentricity of the .NET flavor of regex, or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Ahmad Mageed beat me to it. Removal of the $ is required. In the following code, your 3 lines are printed out, with 2.1 been the first match.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myData = "dsfdsaf|2.1" + Environment.NewLine +
                        "wretdfg|2.2" + Environment.NewLine + 
                        "sdafasd3|2.3";

        Regex rex = new Regex(@"^(?<pre>.+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})",RegexOptions.Multiline);
        var m = rex.Matches(myData);
        foreach (var match in m)
        {
            string hello = match.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Draak, glad it worked for you. Reg Expressions can be a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '?' to make the '+' lazy instead of greedy. It will grab as few characters as it can while still fulfilling the regex.

```
Dim rgx = New Regex("^(?<pre>.+?)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

If you know that the text preceeding the version number will not contain any pipes, you could also replace the . with the [^\|] character class.

```
Dim rgx = New Regex("^(?<pre>[^\|]+)(\|\d\.\d{1,2})$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Comment: I actually tried the lazy option before, but it also didn't work. There are pipes in the <pre>. I just gave a simplified example for input. Thanks though.